# Ubuntu 22.04 multiple virtual interface on one NIC

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, network-adapter, ubuntu-22.04

I'm reading this instruction, but it seems to be broken for Ubuntu 22.04.
I want to have an self assigned static IP address and a DHCP given IP address using one network interface.
How can I define multiple virtual interfaces on Ubuntu 22.04 and set one to DHCP and the other to manual static IP assigning?

Comment: You don't need "virtual interfaces" for that, unless you are talking about VLAN.